# test if element is array c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, detection

how would i detect if an element is an array? also, how would i declare an array like this: `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

In C, multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, not an array where one element is another array but the others are numbers. `int x[10][10]` declares `x` as an array of 10 arrays of 10 `int`s, i.e. 100 total elements in a 10 x 10 matrix.

To do what you describe, you'd need an array of `void *`s:

```
struct myarr {
  size_t len;
  void **arr;
};
```

You allocate `len` elements for `arr` with `x.arr = malloc(x.len * sizeof(void *))`. Then each element can be anything you want - perhaps a number, perhaps another `struct myarr` for further nesting.

In practice, however, you'll have no way of knowing whether the `void *` is a number or another array. So you'll need some sort of dynamic type checking.

```
enum mytype {
  INT,
  ARR,
};
```

Then you make a `struct myint` and redo `struct myarr` to be compatible:

```
struct myint {
  enum mytype type;
  int i;
};

struct myarr {
  enum mytype type;
  size_t len;
  enum mytype **arr;
};
```

When you make a `struct myint`, always set `x.type = INT`, and when you make a `struct myarr`, always set `x.type = ARR`.

`struct` pointers can always be cast to a pointer to the first element, so both `struct myint *` and `struct myarr *` can be cast to an `enum mytype *` pointer, which is what your array in `myarr` holds. Then, when you access an element of the array with `.arr[n]`, you can test (at runtime) what type it holds, cast the pointer accordingly, and use at will:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.len, i++)
  {
    enum mytype *j = x.arr[i];
    if(*j == INT)
      {
        printf("%i", ((struct myint *)j)->i);
      }
    else if(*j == ARR)
      {
        printf("[");
        // recurse
        printf("]");
      }
    else /* this should not happen, you messed up */;
  }
```

There are various other ways to achieve fundamentally the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C absolutely can't do that -- they can't hold collections of objects that aren't all the same type. The same is true of the collections classes in the C++ standard library. To create this kind of "heterogeneous" collection, you actually need to define some kind of struct (or class in C++) -- call it `DataObject`, for example -- and then arrange for `DataObject` to be able to represent different types, often by using a `union`. Then everything in the array can be a `DataObject`, but some can be `DataObject`s that hold an `int`, and others that hold another `DataObject` array.